# Подскажите что это за паттерн проектирования?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблоны

Есть код, не могу понять что это за паттерн, похоже на реализацию итератора, подскажите плиз

```
class MainApp
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Class1[] cr = new Class1[2];

        cr[0] = new Class2();
        cr[1] = new Class3();

        foreach (Class1 c in cr)
        {
            Class4 pr = c.Method();
            Console.WriteLine("Created {0}", pr.GetType().Name);

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    abstract class Class4 { }
    class Class5 : Class4 { }
    class Class6 : Class4 { }
    abstract class Class1 { public abstract Class4 Method(); }

    class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public override Class4 Method()
        {
            return new Class5();
        }
    }
    class Class3 : Class1
    {
        public override Class4 Method()
        {
            return new Class6();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не код, а шифр какой-то, все названия классов - обфускат. Нет, это не итератор, скорее фабричный метод.

Comment: За что минусы ставите? Нормальный вопрос, есть что объяснить. Я отвечу.

Comment: @aepot если только вопрос привести в нормальный вид. в текущем виде он для всех, кроме самомго ТС, является бесполезным

Comment: @aepot спасибо за ответ, если я правильно понял, реализация фабричного метода в переопределении Method() ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский здесь процентов 80% таких "бесполезных" вопросов каждый день, и никто не минусует, даже плюсы ставят.

Comment: @aepot видимо плюсы ставят из жалости)) типа новенький (подобного рода действия видел неоднократно)  ..хз)) мне вообще пофиг.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну тогда отзовите свое решение :) вопрос отвечен, SO хуже от него не будет. А те кто мунусует уже овтеченные вопросы и принятые ответы - вообще не люди.

Comment: @aepot а то, что 80% такое и никак не противодействует - вот и получаем помойку, хотя цель у ресурса всегда была конкретная))) Сейчас это, как писалось на мете, консультационный центр для новичков)) .. но это проблема и головная боль создателей ресурса, не наша

Comment: @aepot ну вопрос если отвечен то даже если его закроют и заминусуют - он не удалится. Так система сделана

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не понимаю, как то что вы сказали, относится именно к этому вопросу? Этот вопрос совсем не помойка и по ключевым словам "фабрика" будет найден на него ответ. В ответе стандартная реализация фабрики, он явно может быть полезным. Я не вижу ни одной причины называть это помойкой.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский с другой стороны, если этот вопрос точно не будет удален, то смысл насыпать автору минусов? Желаете, чтобы он что-то исправил в вопросе? Но вы не сделали ни одного конструктивного предложения по его исправлению. "привести в нормальный вид" - это как именно по-вашему? Я готов помочь автору с оформлением.

Comment: @aepot "*кто мунусует уже овтеченные вопросы и принятые ответы - вообще не люди. *" --  да нуу. хватит что ли как-то так с плеча. Вот есть вопрос типа: "как мне сделать операционную систему?" и ответ: "смотрите уроки на ютубе и у вас всё получится". Ответ принят.... это не минусовать и не удалять? Бред)) Так что выводы вы делаете слишком абсолютные, как ситх :D

Comment: @aepot с чего вы взяли что я минусовал? Вот пишите тем, кто минусует :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский _смотрите уроки на ютубе_ - я сам бы на удаление его флагнул. Странное сравнение. Ну ок, не минусовали так не минусовали, мне значит показалось так как вы отреагировали на мой коммент.

Comment: @aepot   "*я сам бы на удаление его флагнул*" --- вот. просто вы сразу написали абсолютное утверждение.......... "*так как вы отреагировали на мой коммент.*" --- я скорее отвечал на то что "нормальный вопрос".

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "на удаление флагнул" != "поставил бы минус"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не код, а шифр какой-то, все названия классов - обфускат. Нет, это не итератор, это фабрика.

Если этот код переписать нормально, получится что-то такое

```
abstract class ItemBase { }
class ItemFirst : ItemBase { }
class ItemSecond : ItemBase { }

abstract class FactoryBase
{ 
    public abstract ItemBase CreateItem(); 
}

class ItemFirstFactory : FactoryBase
{
    public override ItemBase CreateItem()
    {
        return new ItemFirst();
    }
}
class ItemSecondFactory : FactoryBase
{
    public override ItemBase CreateItem()
    {
        return new ItemSecond();
    }
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FactoryBase[] factories = new FactoryBase[2];

    factories[0] = new ItemFirstFactory();
    factories[1] = new ItemSecondFactory();

    foreach (FactoryBase factory in factories)
    {
        ItemBase item = factory.CreateItem();
        Console.WriteLine("Created {0}", item.GetType().Name);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Created ItemFirst
Created ItemSecond
```

Для реализации фабрик использовался шаблон "Фабричный метод".